# What do i need to do, to make this trim method work?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5mHH.png)I'm trying to use trim to figure out if someone imputed an empty string, and return the response " Say something, please". This is the peace of code:

```
else if(statement.trim().length() == 0 )
        {
           response = "Say something, please";
        }
```

Comment: Where's your string instance to call `trim` on? You also have no question...

Comment: Plus, `isEmpty()`.

Comment: Empty string has nothing to do with trim(). You should be using isEmpty() and == null.

Comment: @user3437460 If `String` would be a local variable (and not a class reference), his code would work perfectly fine. Although `isEmpty()` might be prefered for readability.

Comment: Besides `isEmpty()` is not the method the OP is looking for.

Comment: @user3437460 if an 'empty String' from the OP means `""`, I agree. Though it seems like the OP also want to catch whitespace-characters-only Strings. In which case a `trim()` call is a good solution. (And yea, the real problem is the call to the String class (possibly) instead on a String instance)

Comment: Did you mean `statement.trim().length()`?

Comment: yes @Andreas but I'm still not getting the response I want

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: @Juan Herrera Well, this place is for asking specific questions. The solutions here already solved your issue. You can't expect all your errors to be fixed by continuously editing your question after we solved your old issue. You are making all the solutions here becoming irrelevant.

Comment: @n247s now it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke the methods from String, you invoke from the String variable. Not the String class.

You probably wanted:

```
else if(userInput.trim().length() == 0)
```

where `userInput` is the string object you are interested to check whether it is empty.

Comment: this helped a lot, thanks

Comment: @JuanHerrera If your issue is solved, you may accept **one** solution here which helped you most by clicking the hollow looking tick beside the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Danny said.

Before your if/else branches you should have a string variable already. Then you simply call trim on that variable.

```
String s = "Hey this isn't empty!!   ";

if(false){
     // never runs
else if(s.trim().length() == 0){
     response = "Say something please";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- You  need first to create an instance of String

  String Str = new String();
- Then  invocke   trim  methid

  str.trim();

Comment: `String str = new String()` ?? This is bad practice.

Comment: Btw, I didn't down vote you